# Equivalent of NSData :subdataWithRange in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, nsdata, equivalent

What is the Java equivalent of `NSData` `:subdataWithRange`? I am working on decrypting certain responses I send from a server I created it works fine in the iOS app written in `Objective-C` but wondering about its equivalent in `Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and convert things to a `byte[]`. `ByteBuffer` is another alternative.